# HtmlAgilityPack XML Capturing following sibling

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, html-agility-pack

Below is the sample input for my HAP.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<html>
  <div class="category">Name:</div>
  <div class="category1">Company ABC</div>
  <div class="category">ID:</div>
  <div class="category1">1</div>
  <div class="category">Location:</div>
  <div class="category1">Home ABC</div>
  <div class="category1">Home DEF</div>
</html>
```

Using `XPath` is it possible to capture the following-sibling of an element delimited by the previous element attribute value? In this case, I would like to store it in a List:

```
"Name" , {"Company ABC"}
"ID", {"1"}
"Location", {"Home ABC", "Home DEF"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe it is possible with just XPaths, but it is definitely possible with XSLT.

This XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="div[@class='category']">
    <div>
      <div class="category">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </div>
      <div>
        <xsl:variable name="nextCategoryCount" select="count(following-sibling::div[@class='category'])"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="following-sibling::div[count(following-sibling::div[@class='category']) = $nextCategoryCount]">
          <xsl:copy-of select="."/>          
        </xsl:for-each>
      </div>
    </div>

  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/html">
    <html>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="div[@class='category']"/>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

applied to the sample XML produces this:

```
<html>
  <div>
    <div class="category">Name:</div>
    <div>
      <div class="category1">Company ABC</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="category">ID:</div>
    <div>
      <div class="category1">1</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="category">Location:</div>
    <div>
      <div class="category1">Home ABC</div>
      <div class="category1">Home DEF</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</html>
```

The job is done by the XPath:

```
following-sibling::div[count(following-sibling::div[@class='category']) = $nextCategoryCount]
```

where `$nextCategoryCount` is set to the number of categories following the current one. This cannot work in pure XPath because there is no way to set that variable before executing the expression.